# Get more than 1000 records in Toad Data Point

Tags: oracle, toad-data-point

When I run a query in an Editor window in Toad Data Point it starts by returning the first 1,000 rows. You have to click the "Last record" button to get the rest of the results. Is there a way to change this behavior and have it return all the rows?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your version but it should look like the below:

[image: Numbers of rows initially fetch]